# SUM( A + B ) vs SUM(A) + SUM(B)

Tags: sum

I came across a script written by one of my coworkers and found a line like the following

```
SELECT SUM(A) + SUM(B) FROM TABLE
```

I proposed a different approach

```
SELECT SUM( A + B ) FROM TABLE
```

Which line is most efficient?

Comment: They won't return the same results necessarily if either column contains nulls. As for efficiency you would need to state your RDBMS though I doubt it will make much difference in any.

Answer (score 3):

For the InnoDB/MySQL 5.6 table with 30M+ rows of `FLOAT`s result is the next.

```
select SUM(x + y) from points;
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 1  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 8,596 sec. */

select SUM(x + y) from points;
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 1  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 8,799 sec. */

select SUM(x) + SUM(y) from points;
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 1  Warnings: 0  Duration for 2 queries: 8,720 sec. */

select SUM(x) + SUM(y) from points;
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 1  Warnings: 0  Duration for 2 queries: 8,580 sec. */

select SUM(x + y) from points;
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 1  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 8,642 sec. */
```

In general the timings are of the same range so i suppose the difference is unsignificant.